# Find all possible file links in a string and set a download button with a link of them inside

Tags: php, regex, file, preg-replace, preg-match

I wanna change the code below to get all possible files with all possible extensions and not just `exe`, `zip`, `rar`, `bin` etc.

```
$find=array('~(<a(.*)href="([^"]*.exe)"(.*)>)([^<]*)(</a>)~',
'~(<a(.*)href="([^"]*.zip)"(.*)>)([^<]*)(</a>)~',
'~(<a(.*)href="([^"]*.rar)"(.*)>)([^<]*)(</a>)~',
'~(<a(.*)href="([^"]*.bin)"(.*)>)([^<]*)(</a>)~');

$matches[$i][1] = preg_replace($find, '<p>$0</p><a href=$3 class="btn btn-success" download>Download</a>',$matches[$i][1]);
```

Comment: no i don't, but i want to get all the possible extensions permutation in one code @fronthem

Comment: You could have just had `(<a(.*)href="([^"]*\.(?:exe|zip|rar|bin))"(.*)>)([^<]*)(</a>)` to start with. If you are copy/pasting the same code multiple times you should look at it a second time. Per your comment below that you want an extension between 2-4 characters you could do `(<a(.*)href="([^"]*\..{2,4})"(.*)>)([^<]*)(</a>‌​)`; or you could swap the `.` to a character class allowing only alphanumerical characters. You may want to look at what characters are allowed as extensions for the OS you are using.

Comment: i feel so stupid now, thanks @chris85

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I could give you some simple example that you can apply to you work

```
<a href="(?:\.\/)?(?:[^\/"]+\/)*[^\/"]*\.([a-zA-Z]+)">
```

This regex will try to capture file extension in the open `<a ...>` tag.

**Explanation**

`(?:\.\/)?` match a prefix `./` of file path if it exists,

`(?:[^\/"]+\/)*` match any possible paths that end with `/` e.g. `this/is/my/path/`,

`[^\/"]*` match a file name,

`\.` match a dot,

`([a-zA-Z]+)` match a file extension.

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/FFulDl/6)

Comment: Not working properly, can you implement the code in my example?

Comment: What do you want to do? match or capture which part of `<a..>` tag.

Comment: it's not wrong, it's the only one which works. You can try it, yours doesn't work

Comment: `<a href="part i wanna have containg link +filename+extension ">FileName</a>`

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/UPyMx3/2 this is an another version that support multi attributes.

Comment: This is too long discussion. My code is actually work, somehow. But you want something that specific than that. My advice is you have to edit you question and provide more information. e.g. sample data, expected output which mention clearly that what do you want to do e.g. capture, match.

Comment: Thanks :* 
  
`$find= '~(<a(.*)href="([^"]*.([a-zA-Z]+))"(.*)>)([^<]*)(</a>)~';`

  This one worked

Answer (score 0):

In theory there's a nearly infinite number of files and extensions, if you want to capture all of them, replace

```
*.exe
```

with

```
*.*
```

and that should capture everything

Comment: Can you give a more complete example in your opening post?   This really should work out for you since * is a wildcard.  I'm interested to see your example, can you post it on ideone?

Comment: i wanna get file extension up to 2 to 4 places after (.)

Comment: `.* ` is anything (except new lines).

Comment: it gets `/` too and i don't want that. @chris85